# Create/Display a welcome message in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a welcome message after a user submit his email but, after first submit my msg start to show randomly. How to fix this.

```js
function emailVerification() {

  var emailContato = document.getElementById("emailForm").value;

  if (emailContato.trim() == "") {
    alert("Email inválido!");
  } else {

    alert('Email cadastrado com sucesso!');
    document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = "Seja bem vindo" + " " + emailContato + "!";
    document.getElementById("boas-vindas").style.visibility = "visible";

    const event = document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  }
}
```

```css
#boas-vindas {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #121;
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: "Georgia", Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="boas-vindas">
  <label id="teste">Mensagem</label>
</div>

<div>      
  <input type="email" id="emailForm" name="Email" placeholder="Coloque seu email de contato! :)">
  <button type="submit" id="btnForm" onclick="emailVerification()">ENVIAR</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Is your problem that after submiting page gets blank?

Comment: I've noticed that your form does the default submittion. Why exactly do you have a form? Like @dommilosz said, if your problem is the page submitting the form and refreshing, you can change your function to take a parameter, `e`, and do `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thx  dommilosz, yes. I'm trying to show a msg but sometimes works and others doesn't.

Thx @programmerRaj. I deleted tag <form> and add the event.preventDefault and works.

I just started to read/learn html+Js...thx again, both of u.

Comment: The snippet works fine for me?